# How to have average of dates

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The final date value should be something like `20080405` but this is showing as `20080229`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(dt);

        List<DateTime> arryDates = new List<DateTime>();

         Decimal[] avgdatetimevalues = { 20080229, 20080304, 20080304, 20080224 };//(Sum = 80321061; sum/4 = 20080265)
         // the final date value should be something like 20080405 but this is showing as 20080229


        try
        {
            for(int i = 0; i< avgdatetimevalues.Length; i++)
            {
                arryDates.Add(ValueToDate(avgdatetimevalues[i]));
            }
            var cnt = arryDates.Count();
            double temp = 0D;
            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                {
                    temp += ( arryDates[i].Ticks / (double)cnt);
                }
                var average = new DateTime((long)temp);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }


    }
    public static DateTime ValueToDate(decimal dt)
    {
        DateTime dates;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(dt.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dates);
        return dates;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post what code you have tried?

Comment: Have added my implementation code and looking for the final date value

Comment: How can the "average" of some dates (whatever that means) fall *after* all the dates? 2008-02-29 plus a few hours actually sounds correct.  Also, why are you using decimals instead of actual DateTime objects?

Comment: The date value is provided as 8 digit number in a raw text file, The req. is to provide average dates. So i.e why i had it double

Answer (score -1):

How do you contain this data?

You can contain them in List, something like this:

```
List<decimal> values = new List<decimal> { 20080229, 20080304, 20080304, 20080224 };
```

And then using something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(values.Average());
```

to get average values of all data from your list.
It's easy :)

Comment: That is what the OP tried to do. It doesn't work because dates aren't numbers - adding 100 to 20081229 returns 20081329, a meaningless value. In fact, the OP's attempt to convert to ticks probably makes more sense than adding arbitrary numbers